# Локализация php

Tags: php

Делал локализацию, получилось все очень громоздко.

Как это исправить?

```
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {

    if ($_GET['lang'] === "ru") $lang = "ru";   

    elseif ($_GET['lang'] === "ua") $lang = "ua";

    else $lang = "en";

    setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+30758400, "/");

} else {
       if (empty($_COOKIE['lang'])) {

            $b_lang = substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2);

            if ($b_lang == "ru") $lang = "ru";

            elseif ($b_lang == "uk") $lang = "ua";

            else $lang = "en";

        }

        else {

            if ($_COOKIE['lang'] === "ru") $lang = "ru";    

            elseif ($_COOKIE['lang'] === "ua") $lang = "ua";

            else $lang = "en";

        }
}

if ($lang === "ru") include("lang/ru.php");

elseif ($lang === "ua") include("lang/ua.php");

else include("lang/en.php");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$allowedLang=array("ru","ua","en");
$needCookie=false;
if(isset($_GET['lang']))
 {
  $lang=$_GET['lang'];
  $needCookie=true;
 }
elseif(empty($_COOKIE['lang'])) $lang=substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2);
else $lang=$_COOKIE['lang'];

if(in_array($lang,$allowedLang)) $lang='en';

if($needCookie) setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+30758400, "/");
include("lang/$lang.php");
```

Ну и совсем хардкорный:

```
<?php
$lang=isset($_GET['lang'])?$_GET['lang']:(empty($_COOKIE['lang'])?substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2):$_COOKIE['lang']);
if($lang!='ru' && $lang!='ua') $lang='en';
if($_GET['lang']) setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+30758400, "/");
include("lang/$lang.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Больше вариантов :)

```
function resolveLanguage()
{
    // эти значения стоит хранить где-то в конфиге
    // чтобы потом не надо было менять код
    $allowedLanguages = array('ru', 'ua', 'en');
    $defaultLanguage = 'en';

    // порядок имеет значение
    // можно добавить еще какой-то источник для определения языка
    $preferredLanguages = array(
        isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : null,
        isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ? $_COOKIE['lang']: null,
        substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2),
    );

    // убираем лишние, хотя смысла в этом нет - можно убрать (см. ниже)
    $preferredLanguages = array_filter($preferredLanguages);

    // выбираем первый разрешенный язык
    foreach ($preferredLanguages as $language) {
        if (in_array($language, $allowedLanguages)) {
            return $language;
        }
    }

    // если ничего не нашли..
    return $defaultLanguage;
}

function saveLanguage($language)
{
   setcookie("lang", $language, time()+30758400, "/");
}
```

Использование:

```
$language = resolveLanguage();

include("lang/{$language}.php");
saveLanguage($language); // ну не знаю, почему после, вдруг на include всё сдохло :)
```

Делать код коротким неправильно (*в данном случае*). Он должен быть понятным и легко обновляемым/настраиваемым.

upd.
В php 7.0 можно написать так:

```
    $preferredLanguages = array(
        $_GET['lang'] ?? null,
        $_COOKIE['lang'] ?? null,
        substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2),
    );
```

Comment: Вы setcookie забыли

Comment: *Делать код коротким неправильно* <<< so true

Comment: точно, не заметил ``setCookie`` (обновил ответ)

Comment: После include я бы не рискнул, вдруг include уже выведет что нибудь на страницу и он тогда не сработает

Comment: Согласен, пусть автор вопроса об этом подумает.